# How to check if clearTimeout was called with sinon.useFakeTimers?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, cleartimeout

I'm using `sinon` with [fake timers](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.1.2/fake-timers/) and I want to check if `clearTimeout` was called with a specific timeout-id.

```
var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
functionUnderTest();
// How can I know if functionUnderTest cleared a specific timeout?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `clock` object has sinon's timer related functions, you can `spy` them and then assert that they were called

```
var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
sinon.spy(clock, "clearTimeout");

functionUnderTest();

sinon.assert.calledWith(clock.clearTimeout, 42);
```